# Update a table using aggregate of another table efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using

```
UPDATE main 
SET val = (
    SELECT SUM(..) 
    FROM other 
    WHERE main.id=other.main_id 
    GROUP BY main_id
)
```

However other has optional participation so when it runs, update seems to null out val when it is not found in the other table. Instead it should only update val for id that exist in the subquery.

How do I fix this?

Edit:
I managed to fix it by adding

```
WHERE IN SELECT main_id FROM other
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update main 
set val = coalesce(
    select sum(..) 
    from other 
    where main.id=other.main_id 
    group by main_id
), val)
```

If the subquery returns null it will set `val`to `val`

Or better

```
update main 
set val = s.val_sum
from (
    select sum(..) as val_sum, main_id 
    from other 
    group by main_id
) s
where s.main_id = main.id
```

Comment: When I run your second query the planner chooses to hash the main table (which is larger) then perform a hash join. I would think that it would be faster to hash the table from the subquery or even just do a nested loop join. Is there a way to achieve that without messing with configurations?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE main SET val = 
   (SELECT count(*) FROM other WHERE main.id=other.main_id)
WHERE exists (select 1 from other where main.id=other.main_id)
```